# Add Computer Device to AAD Group via Graph API in Powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

how do i add a computer device to an existing AAD security group?
I create a token with this

```
$Body = @{
    'tenant'        = $TenantId
    'client_id'     = $ClientId
    'scope'         = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
    'client_secret' = $ClientSecret
    'grant_type'    = 'client_credentials'
}

$Params = @{
    'Uri'         = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
    'Method'      = 'Post'
    'Body'        = $Body
    'ContentType' = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

$AuthResponse = Invoke-RestMethod @Params

$Headers = @{
    'Authorization' = "Bearer $($AuthResponse.access_token)"
}
```

After that i can make queries to the Graph API.
Fetching group information

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<GUID_group>' -Headers $Headers
```

Getting the correct result with all information of the group.

The [microsoft documentatios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) says to add a member use this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/$ref
```

But where i do define the ObjectID of the computer device? If i run the request like above, nothing will happen, like described in the microsoft docs.

This one also would not work:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<GUID_group>/members/<GUID_computer>
```

Then it says that the group does not exists

```
"error": {
 "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
 "message": "Resource '<GUID_group>' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",
 "innerError": {
   "date": "2020-08-25T12:47:10",
   "request-id": "bc728016..."
 }
}
```

Neither `GET` nor `POST` works.

Any ideas or is more information needed?

Maybe i am using the wrong query to accomplish what i want to do. I took a look at the `directoryObject` querys, but everytime i got refered to the *Add member to group* Site

Thanks!

Comment: `"You can add users, organizational contacts, service principals or other groups."` From the linked documentation.

Comment: It also says `directoyObject`, an i think a device/computer is a directoryObject. Maybe its the wrong query. Thats because i'm asking. Thanks for the reply :-)

Comment: Please provide correlation id and timestamp of error message

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query in the graph explorer

You can get group id by running below query

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
```

To get device id by running below query

```
Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices
```

To add the device into the group use groupid and deviceid for below query and you get 204 response

```
Post https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/members/$ref
{
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/deviceid"
}
```

By using below query you will get the details of group where your device memberof

```
 GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/devices/deviceid/memberOf
```

[image]